# Handling request for CLLocationManager authorization in an XCTest case

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, unit-testing, xctest

I'm working on writing some unit tests for some code that uses core location. I've got a function that will do different things depending on whether or not it has authorization to access the user's location.

If I were to run the app, grant it access to the location, and then run the test it will be able to test having authorization to location, and if I were to reset the simulator then test, it's able to test the part where it doesn't have access. While this kinda works, it's a huge pain, and definitely not automated. Especially since these tests are run by a CI server, I need a better solution.

So, is there a way to set the authorizationStatus for the CLLocationManager from XCTest, or even tap on allow access on the system prompt?

Comment: I don't think there is, unless you mock the object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a Facade that interacts with the CLLocationManager. Access this Facade using some form of [Dependency Injection](https://www.objc.io/issues/15-testing/dependency-injection/). Then your tests can inject a fake, letting you *simulate* the results of calling your Facade. (You probably want a separate test for each CLAuthorizationStatus value.)